# Obj-C, iOS, how do I write / use a standard class which will contain touchesBegan and touchesMoved etc?

Tags: objective-c

I'm going to be using the same code that I have in my view controller in several views and I don't want to have to paste the code into each.

Can someone show me a few lines of code showing me how to do this ?

I'm guessing i'm going to have to declare an instance of the class in the interface and put a hand back method for each of touch functions I'll be sub classing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want the same bit of code executed for touchesBegan, touchesMoved... from each of your views.

The way I would do this would be using the delegate pattern.

```
@protocol ViewTouchDelegate
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
@end

@interface ViewA : UIView {
    id <ViewTouchDelegate> touchDelegate;
}

@implementation ViewA
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self->touchDelegate touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
@end // End View A

@interface ViewB : UIView {
    id <ViewTouchDelegate> touchDelegate;
}

@implementation ViewB
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self->touchDelegate touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
@end // End View B
```

This will let you put all your touch handling code in one place (in a class that conforms to the ViewTouchDelegate protocol), and give that delegate to each of your views.

In my example I have made the signature of touchesBegan the same as UIResponder's touchesBegan, but you can tailor it to your needs.

Edit: Example ViewTouchDelegate

```
@interface MyViewTouchDelegate : NSObject <ViewTouchDelegate>
@end

@implementation MyViewTouchDelegate
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //put all your common touch handling code in here
}
@end
```

Define any additional methods you need in the ViewTouchDelegate protocol for your purposes, for example touchesMoved, touchesEnded, yourOwnCustomEvent.

Comment: OK, can you edit to include an example for implementation of ViewTouchDelegate please.

Comment: @Jules added example as requested. Your views would also require a property to set the touchDelegate

Answer (score 1):

Create a proper super class that will **need** to be subclassed in order to perform the specific tasks you need it for. This is one of the many reasons why OOP is so awesome :P

For instance every object you create in objective-c is a subclass of NSObject, which contains standard methods like release retain and init, which initially creates the object.

If you would be like coding a game, you could create a super class that is called object, which would be subclassed for specifying certain types of objects like props or ragdolls.

Comment: Erm, OK, I think. How do I do that then ?

Comment: Objective-C beginners guide can be found here: http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html

Answer (score 1):

As *Antwan* and *jjwchoy* mentioned there are several ways of doing something like this. In most OOP languages, subclassing is the preferred way. A subclass inherits all of the treats of its superclass as well as your custom behavior. To do this you would implement a class in a way similar to what you see below:

In **JULView.h** (the name of your new class) there would be some code like this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
//... #import for all of the other classes/libraries you need

@interface JULView : UIView
{
  // your iVars go here
}

// Your Custom Properties and Methods go here
- (void)customMethod

@end
```

And In the implementation file (**JULView.m**)

```
#import "JULView.h"

// Synthesize your properties here
@implementation JULView

#pragma mark - Initialization
- (id)init
{
  [super init];
  // Additional initialization
}

#pragma mark - Custom methods
- (void)customMethod1
{
  // A custom method code
}

#pragma mark - Overwritten UIView Methods
// Your touch handling stuff
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  // Your code
}

@end
```

To use this new subclass, simply import the header file

```
#import "JULView.h"
```

into the class you are using and instantiate JULView just as you would a UIView

```
// instead of
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] init];

// you would use
JULView *aView = [[JULView alloc] init];
```

In addition to subclassing, Objective-C provides a few more ways of achieving this: the delegate pattern and categories. *jjwchoy* did an excellent job describing a common way of implementing the use of delegates, so there is no need to regurgitate it. Instead, let's go over categories.

Categories *extend* an existing class with additional methods or with *your version* of existing methods. For example, let's say you want to add a method that returns the first letter of a string to NSString. To do this you would create a category as follows:

Interface - **JULString.h**

```
#import NSString

@interface NSString (JULString)

-(NSString *) firstLetter;

@end
```

Implementation - The typical convention is that the filename of the category is the name of the class you are extending followed by “+” and the name of the category. In this case the file would be called **NSString+JULString.m**

```
#import "NSString+JULString.h"

@implementation NSString ( JULString )

- (NSString *)firstLetter
{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [self characterAtIndex:1]];
}
@end
```

The neat thing about categories is that now they extend the behavior of ANY instance of the class you are working with. In other words, any NSString in your application will have your new methods (provided that you import the proper header file of course). Beware though, as with great power comes great responsibility. Overwriting class using a category behaviors *may* lead to undesired effects, so be cautious.

A couple of links you may want to check are:

- [Apple's guide to Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)
- [Learn Objective-C](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)

*Note:*
I don't have my Mac with me so I'm writing this code basically off the top of my head (and using some code from the sites above as a reminder). So I apologize in advance for any mistakes ;)