# How to set up non-instantiated classes in Objective-C (Classes with just methods)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, class

I'm looking to create a class in Objective-C for an iOS project that is focused on fetching data. I'm familiar with how classes normally work, setter and getter methods and variables. However, for this class since it's only performing a function (returning NSMutableArrays) I don't want to have to create an instance of the class to use the methods inside the class.

Any idea how I can do this neatly and efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make class methods?

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {}
+(NSMutableArray*)someClassMethod:(id)params;
@end

...

@implementation Foo
+(NSMutableArray*)someClassMethod:(id)params {
   // whatever implementation 
   return nil;
}
@end

...

NSMutableArray* array = [Foo someClassMethod:nil];
```

Comment: @Matthew Frederick: What are you talking about? The class KennyTM wrote here consists only of class methods. You don't need to instantiate it, and in fact creating an instance would be pointless. When you send a message to the class, you *are* talking to something — the class.

Comment: @Chuck I'm babbling, obviously, and shouldn't answer SO questions until I've had my coffee -- didn't notice he'd used class methods, which could have led me further into babbling land. It's been more than 5 minutes so I can't edit it, so I'm going to add a new comment with the portion that's correct and will shortly delete the other comment to avoid future confusion (and save myself from pre-full-wakefulness embarrassment). Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I'll just add for @mac_55 that a class doesn't need to have properties or instance variables, and doesn't need getters and setters.

Comment: @Chuck This has been bugging me, so I tried to figure out what my brain was doing. What I wanted to communicate was that in order to call a class's methods there has to be an instantiated object that implements the method in order to call it. Something wrong with that?

Comment: @Matthew Frederick: It's a little bit misleading IMO when you're talking about class methods. A class *is* an instantiated object, but it's automatically instantiated just by virtue of being in your program. You don't have to instantiate anything yourself.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little bit atypical in Objective-C. Since classes in Objective-C can't actually have state beyond what is available to ordinary functions (i.e. there are no class variables), a class that's never instantiated is relatively useless in most cases. The normal design patterns for this kind of functionality are:

- A singleton class (if you need lots of state)
- A set of functions (if you don't)

Answer (score 2):

If you're only performing functions, and you don't need to support subclassing etc, why not just write them as C functions rather than a class with methods?

Answer (score 2):

If this is just a class that performs some functions, you could write it as a C function.

In your header file --

```
NSMutableArray *functionThatReturnsMutableArray(NSObject *param1, NSString *param2);
```

In your implementation file --

```
NSMutableArray *functionThatReturnsMutableArray(NSObject *param1, NSString *param2)
{
   ...
   return aMutableArray;
}
```

And that just include the .h file in your class that needs these functions and call them directly.

```
NSMutableArray *anArray = functionThatReturnsMutableArray(param1, param2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing (the same NSString operations, UIView manipulations, etc), you could implement a category (I answered [a question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896270/obj-c-ios-how-do-i-write-use-a-standard-class-which-will-contain-touchesbegan/6021830#6021830) with the explanation below -- copied for your convenience ;).

Categories *extend* an existing class with additional methods or with *your version* of existing methods. For example, let's say you want to add a method that returns the first letter of a string to NSString. To do this you would create a category as follows:

Interface - **JULString.h**

```
#import NSString

@interface NSString (JULString)

-(NSString *) firstLetter;

@end
```

Implementation - The typical convention is that the filename of the category is the name of the class you are extending followed by “+” and the name of the category. In this case the file would be called **NSString+JULString.m**

```
#import "NSString+JULString.h"

@implementation NSString ( JULString )

- (NSString *)firstLetter
{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [self characterAtIndex:1]];
}
@end
```

The neat thing about categories is that now they extend the behavior of ANY instance of the class you are working with. In other words, any NSString in your application will have your new methods (provided that you import the proper header file of course). Beware though, as with great power comes great responsibility. Overwriting class using a category behaviors *may* lead to undesired effects, so be cautious.

A couple of links you may want to check are:

- [Apple's guide to Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)
- [Learn Objective-C](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)

*Note:*
I don't have my Mac with me so I'm writing this code basically off the top of my head (and using some code from the sites above as a reminder). So I apologize in advance for any mistakes ;)